# UDP client/server c

Tags: c, sockets, udp, wireshark

I have been looking everywhere for an answer.  I am new to coding in C and would have loved it if my Professor would have allowed us to choose the language, but I digress.  I am running Oracle V-Box locally running Ubuntu client and a Ubuntu server.  I compile the code below on both the server and the client, with a few warnings.  I run the code on the server (seems fine) and then on the client.  The client is asking to send over a PDF file just like I did with the TCP socket transfer (which worked great).  I also have Wireshark running on the client and server, and it looks like the request is sent out from the client but the server doesn't do anything and just sits on both ends without pulling the file over.  Not sure if it is the code or something else.

```
/* Echo server using UDP */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define SERVER_UDP_PORT     2466    
#define MAXLEN      4096

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     sd, client_len, port, n;
    char    buf[MAXLEN];
    struct  sockaddr_in     server, client;

    switch(argc) {
    case 1:
        port = SERVER_UDP_PORT;
        break;
    case 2:
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [port]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create a datagram socket */
    if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't create a socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Bind an address to the socket */
    bzero((char *)&server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, 
             sizeof(server)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't bind name to socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        client_len = sizeof(client);
        if ((n = recvfrom(sd, buf, MAXLEN, 0, 
                          (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_len)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't receive datagram\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (sendto(sd, buf, n, 0, 
                   (struct sockaddr *)&client, client_len) != n) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't send datagram\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(sd);
    return(0);
}
```

This is the client code

```
// UDP Echo Client

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#define SERVER_UDP_PORT         2466
#define MAXLEN                  4096
#define DEFLEN                  64

long delay(struct timeval t1, struct timeval t2)
{
    long d;
    d = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000;
    d += ((t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec + 500) / 1000);
    return(d);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     data_size = DEFLEN, port = SERVER_UDP_PORT;
    int     i, j, sd, server_len;
    char    *pname, *host, rbuf[MAXLEN], sbuf[MAXLEN];
    struct  hostent         *hp;
    struct  sockaddr_in     server;
    struct  timeval         start, end;
    unsigned long address;

    pname = argv[0];
    argc--;
    argv++;
    if (argc > 0 && (strcmp(*argv, "-s") == 0)) {
        if (--argc > 0 && (data_size = atoi(*++argv))) {
            argc--;
            argv++;
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Usage: %s [-s data_size] host [port]\n", pname);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (argc > 0) {
        host = *argv;
        if (--argc > 0)
            port = atoi(*++argv);
    }

    else {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Usage: %s [-s data_size] host [port]\n", pname);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't create a socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero((char *)&server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    if ((hp = gethostbyname(host)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't get server's IP address\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *) &server.sin_addr, hp->h_length);

    if (data_size > MAXLEN) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Data is too big\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
        j = (i < 26) ? i : i % 26;
        sbuf[i] = 'a' + j;
    } // construct data to send to the server
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL); /* start delay measurement */
    server_len = sizeof(server);
    if (sendto(sd, sbuf, data_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)
               &server, server_len) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "sendto error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (recvfrom(sd, rbuf, MAXLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)
                 &server, &server_len) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "recvfrom error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL); /* end delay measurement */
    if (strncmp(sbuf, rbuf, data_size) != 0)
        printf("Data is corrupted\n");
    close(sd);
    return(0);
}
```

Once I compile I run the code on Server normally:

```
./udp_server
```

and just sits waiting from the client.

Once I compile I run the code on Client:

```
./udp_client -s 1500 10.0.2.11 2466 > test.pdf
```

I run this which is (./udp_client -s data_rate server_IP Server_Port > (output to file on desktop of client))

This just produces a blank page.  It should have a few pages of text and pics.

I also am getting the send out from client on Wireshark but no reply from server.
[image]

This is what i am getting when i run STRACE from terminal

[strace ./udp_server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDEa6.png)

Comment: Run the server under `strace`.  This will produce a tremendous volume of gobbledygook.  Wait until it stops spewing at your terminal.  Then, without hitting control-C, copy and past the last ten to fifteen lines of gobbledygook, UNEDITED, into the question.  Then run the sending client.  If that causes anything more to appear in the terminal window where the server is running, copy and paste that into the question too, again, UNEDITED.

Comment: Have you tried running the server under a debugger, to see if it's receiving the packets?

Comment: Also run Wireshark on the server to see if it's receiving the packets.

Comment: Wireshark on server side sees the exact same thing that the client sees.  Note: I can ping both sides and both sides pick up ICMP from each others pings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just forgot to print out the received data in the client:

```
if (strncmp(sbuf, rbuf, data_size) != 0)
    printf("Data is corrupted\n");
close(sd);

printf(rbuf);  // <----

return(0);
```

Your client code currently only prints out error messages. If everything works, it won't produce any output.

Comment: @MartinJames: I tested the code locally and it produces the expected result.

Comment: Tried to run with changes...no success.

Comment: @MathiasKroll: Does running the client and server on the same computer work?

Comment: I did run the client and server on same computer and it gave me "abcdefg...etc." for about 10 lines which is new.  Is that what you got?

Comment: would have been cool for someone to figure out two separate client/server instances as oppose to keeping them on the same system.. but whatever...thanks blender and the rest (Marty...had to add his usual two cents...worth about that much)